# Methods in grader

Tags: java, methods

I'm doing a grade calculator that gets the average, then determines final grade as an A,B,C,D,F. But i'm supposed to use only 2 methods calAverage and determineGrade. Im having trouble with methods outside the main. Any help/advice will help! Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MorenoJonathonGrader
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter grades");
  int average = calAverage(int grade);
  int finalGrade = determineGrade();
  System.out.println(grade);
  System.out.println(finalGrade);

  }
public int calAverage(int average){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  for (int i=0; i>5;i++){
  int grade;
 grade = sc.nextInt();
  return grade;
  }


  }
 public int determineGrade(int grade){
  average = finalGrade;
 return finalGrade;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to call non-static methods in static one. Your `main` method is `static`. Methods `calAverage` and `determineGrade` are not, they are bound to the object instance.

Try making them static too:

```
private static int calAverage(List<Integer> grades)
```

and

```
private static char determineGrade(int grade)
```

The other way would be creating your class instance, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MorenoJonathonGrader grader = new MorenoJonathonGrader();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //collect grades
    int average = grader.calAverage(grades);
    char finalGrade = grader.determineGrade(average);
}
```

Check out also this article for better understanding: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)